# Issue parsing json with jackson 1.9

Tags: java, json, class, jackson

I used Gson before and everything worked fine, but it is too slow.

Here is the Json:

```
"{"Info":[{"par1":3456,"par2":4500,"par3":0,"items":{"parx":2354,"pary":456456,"parz":"worker"}}
    ,{"par1":34456,"par2":4300,"par3":1,"items":{"parx":5677,"pary":78456,"parz":"member"}},
    ],"par4":343434,"duplicateItemIdList":null,"errorState":null}"
```

Now I tried Jackson:

code snippets:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Passes mj = mapper.readValue(str, Passes.class);

public class Passes {
    public ArrayList<Info> info;   

.... }

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)    
class Info {

        public String par1 = "";
        public String par2 = "";
        public String par3 = "";
        public String par4 = "";   

        Items items = new Items();    
}

class Items{           
        public String parx = "";
        public String pary = "";
        public String parz = "";
}
```

the Problem is it doesn't fill the class `items`. parx,pary,parz etc

`items` is the only problem. the rest works fine.

my structure has to be right because in Gson I only need two lines and it works perfectly.

so I think I have to add something so that jackson recognizes

Comment: Its good story but where your Json String? please, add it

Comment: i can do but it shouldn't matter cause it works flawlees with gson

Comment: How can we help you if we don't see what you try to convert. It's good that Gson works well but the easiest way right now to create new project in Eclipse and do what you did to find real problem. Because code you posted seems good

Comment: it is over 18000 chars long

Comment: cut off and post only relevant json

Comment: ok i took some examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that you have:

- geters/setters for each parameter
- empty (or any ) Contractor

**Passes**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Passes {
    private List<Info> info;  

    public Passes() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public List<Info> getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public void setInfo(List<Info> info) {
        this.info = info;
    }
}
```

**Info**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)    
public  class Info {

    private int par1;
    private int par2;
    private int par3;
    private int par4;

    //private Items items;    

    public Info() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public int getPar1() {
        return par1;
    }

    public void setPar1(int par1) {
        this.par1 = par1;
    }

    public int getPar2() {
        return par2;
    }

    public void setPar2(int par2) {
        this.par2 = par2;
    }

    public int getPar3() {
        return par3;
    }

    public void setPar3(int par3) {
        this.par3 = par3;
    }

    public int getPar4() {
        return par4;
    }

    public void setPar4(int par4) {
        this.par4 = par4;
    }
}
```

**Items**

```
public class Items{           
    private int parx;
    private int pary;
    private String parz;

    public Items() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public int getParx() {
        return parx;
    }

    public void setParx(int parx) {
        this.parx = parx;
    }

    public int getPary() {
        return pary;
    }

    public void setPary(int pary) {
        this.pary = pary;
    }

    public String getParz() {
        return parz;
    }

    public void setParz(String parz) {
        this.parz = parz;
    }
}
```

It should work

*As a side note*:

`Gson` uses `LinkedLIst` when `Jackson` `ArrayList` therefore from your code `Gson` fail to convert `Passes` class

Comment: thanks. i already had contractors in it. it was just a snippet. and getter and setters didn't solve the problem.

Comment: to the side note: "Passes"-class doesn't fail. just "items" are empty

Comment: the json you posted works well, and I get all data (Items too) so your problem in "original" Json

Comment: seems like jackson needs them and gson doesn't

Comment: `seems like jackson need them and gson doesn't` right, this is a difference in performance. Write less - less performance :)